# Why is Content Type column appearing in New Item form of List

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

All of a sudden when I go to the default new item form in a simple List I see a new field **Content Type** with one option in dropdown menu **Item**. Why is it so? Have the settings been compromised? Kindly help!

[See image for info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xXde.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check your List settings > Advanced Settings.

The Allow management of content types settings is probably set to Yes[image: See image]

Changing it back to no will prevent the **Content Type** field from appearing in the form.

Comment: Before this problem even with Yes selected there was never a field **Content Type** in NewForm or EditForm... I used to set mngmt of content type to **Yes** and change column orders but there was no such field visible. I'm currently working on SharePoint Online

Comment: Looks like it could be related with the new SharePoint experience as the Content Type dropdown does not appear in forms when in classic SharePoint experience with the allow management of content type set to Yes.